# Does a sigma-algebra always contain all open sets?

Tags: measure-theory

This might be an easy question, but I don't really know what to use.

Let $(S,\mathcal{S},d)$ be a seperable metric space, and let furthermore $(S,\mathcal{S})$ be standard  borel

That is there exist a injective map so $\varphi:$ $(S,\mathcal{S} )\mapsto(\mathbb{R} ,\mathcal{B} (\mathbb{R} ))$
where  $\varphi(S)\in \mathcal{B} (\mathbb{R} )$, $\varphi\in\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{S})$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ is $\mathcal{B} (\mathbb{R})-\mathcal{S}$-measurable.

Can I without further assumptions know my metric space contains all open (or closed) sets?

Comment: I don't understand what standard Borel means nor what $\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ and $\mathcal M ( \mathcal S)$ stand for but in general no: the trivial sigma algebra does not contain all Borel sets. If you want the sigma algebra to contain all Borel sets it will have to contain the Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: Standard Borel, according to some papers I read, means S is a complete separable metric space. Hope that's what he also means.

Comment: @MattN.: But the trivial $\sigma$-algebra is not standard Borel: no injective map $\varphi$ satisfying the above conditions exists.  $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, and I suppose $\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{S})$ means that $\varphi$ is measurable, i.e. $\varphi^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal{S}$ for each $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot.

Take $S = \mathbb{R}$, $d$ the Euclidean metric, and $\mathcal{S}$ defined as follows.  Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ be any non-Borel set such that $E$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus E$ both have cardinality continuum.  Then there is a bijection $\varphi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ which maps $(0,1)$ onto $E$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus (0,1)$ onto $\mathbb{R} \setminus E$.  Take $\mathcal{S} = \{ \varphi^{-1}(B) : B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$.  This is clearly a $\sigma$-algebra and $(S, \mathcal{S})$ is standard Borel, since by construction $\varphi$ is a measurable bijection from $(S, \mathcal{S})$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.  But since $E$ is not Borel, we have $(0,1) = \varphi^{-1}(E) \notin \mathcal{S}$, even though $(0,1)$ is open in $(S,d)$.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just haven't thought enough about what implications being standard Borel actually has.